# An alternative to deprecated addKey() method in Magento?

Tags: magento

I am trying to add an index for a column over Magento data setup script.

```
/** @var Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup $installer */
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer
    ->getConnection()
    ->addKey(
        $installer->getTable('enterprise_rma/rma'),
        'IDX_EXPORT_DATE',
        'export_date'
    );
```

However our inspection tool complains:

```
The method Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::addKey() has been deprecated with message: since 1.5.0.0
```

What I can use instead of addKey() in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `addKey` function in the class `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql`:

```
public function addKey($tableName, $indexName, $fields, $indexType = 'index', $schemaName = null)
{
    return $this->addIndex($tableName, $indexName, $fields, $indexType, $schemaName);
}
```

It is just making a call to the `addIndex` function of the same class, this function is not deprecated, so you should use this one.

```
/**
 * Add new index to table name
 *
 * @param string $tableName
 * @param string $indexName
 * @param string|array $fields  the table column name or array of ones
 * @param string $indexType     the index type
 * @param string $schemaName
 * @return Zend_Db_Statement_Interface
 * @throws Zend_Db_Exception|Exception
 */
public function addIndex($tableName, $indexName, $fields,
    $indexType = Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_INDEX, $schemaName = null)
```

(My code come from Magento Enterprise 1.12)